# Update files on github from bash

Tags: git, github

I'm really sorry if this has been asked before, my searching skills are bad.

So I want to update my github repo with my local code, but it always says "Everything up-to-date"
So I have one file I modified, and I try

- git add Main.cs
- git commit -m 'Commit'
- git push origin master

But it still says Up-To-Date even though the file on my local system is different than the one on the repo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you see diff between your local and remote branch?

Comment: What does `git status` say? `git diff` will only look at tracked files.

Comment: yes, I have multiple differences between my remote and local. But the git diff command, I didnt try, if that has to do with this.

Comment: @neontapir "#On branch Master nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: When you do `git config --local --list`, what are the settings for `remote.origin.*` and `branch.master.*`?

Comment: Then git sees no differences. Is Main.cs in origin's master? Have you made an edit to Main.cs and then tried it?

Comment: remote.origin.url=github.com/myname/repo.git and there isnt a branch.master

Comment: @neontapir yes that is what I did

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you may have a configuration problem.

The output of `git config --list --local` should contain this

```
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/myname/repo.git 
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

You should definitely have the settings for `branch.master`. Also, note the protocol `https://` on the `remote.origin.url`.

I would recommend editing your config to contain the four lines, using this command

```
git config --local --edit
```

When you manually edit the file it should look like this

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/myname/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: @somerandomguy definitely not `--global`, since that will set it for all your Git repos. Use `--local` to set it for the current repo only.

Comment: Ah how do I make a new line in vim? also where do I put those lines? NVM  figgured it out

Comment: I added those lines, but now I can't do anything it always says "fatal: bad config file line 15 in .git/config"

Comment: If there are previous settings under the headings `[remote "origin"]` or `[branch "master"]` you should remove those. If there are multiple such headings, you should only have one of each.

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently going to the Udemy class - "GitHub Ultimate: Master Git and GitHub." In reference to your previous problem, I ran into the same problem. I found in VS Code, with Autosave on, you can simply click on the file in your VS Code editor and make the changes. When you enter 'git status', your response will be 'modified: filename.ext' (In the case of Udemy, 'modified: README.md')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems your answer does not directly address the question as the question relates to local and remote repository synchronisation. Thus i suggest you to remove your answer.